# Scheduled job execution time is creeping

Tags: scheduled-job

I have a scheduled job that runs at 10am each day. It just sends a report. 
I'm noticing over time that the job is executing later and later. Now it is executing at 10.15am. Anyone else noticed this and it there a way of fixing it without having to go back into the scheduled job and reset the time?

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem that's popped up and been squashed a few times - it's a little trickier to fix than it seems.

The current conversation about it [is on Gitlab](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/416) but [CRM-17671](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18671) provides some historical perspective.

Your best short-term solution is probably Xavier's answer on a [very similar question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8103/12).